# Extending height of a div within another div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with two wrappers that I am using. I want to make the `#wrapper` always extend to the bottom of the screen. This is now working by using `min-height: 100%;`. Within this div I'm using another wrapper, `#page-wrapper`, which should be extended to the bottom of the `#wrapper` div. To make this work, the `#wrapper` div has to be set to `height: 100%` instead of `min-height`. Is there a way to achieve both?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2f4050;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#page-wrapper {
  padding: 0 15px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had this same problem once. The only way that I found was to do it via js, getting the total outerHeight from the elements that compose the structure of the page and setting the result to the 'parent' div. Try it and tell me if that worked for you.

Comment: Set `margin:0` in _#wrapper_ element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using viewport units.

```css
#page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Example 1:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  background: pink;
}
#page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  background: pink;
}
#page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div style="height:200vh;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```